# how to read a specific set of words in .txt file and generate a randomizer of those words

Tags: python

I wanna open a file named words.txt file and generate words randomly through 1 to 10 depending on which number the user enters.

```
library:la biblioteca
school:el colegio,la escuela
restaurant:el restaurante
movie theater:el cine
airport:el aeropuerto
museum:el museo
park:el parque
university:la universidad
office:la oficina,el despacho
house:la casa
```

Is there a way to read only the "second" part of the words, first line for example. skip "library:", and read "**la biblioteca**" without hardingcoding the words.

```
with open("words.txt", "r") as infile:
    words = infile.readline().split() #This is the line that needs improvement
    random_word = random.choice(words)
    newKeys = False
    for i in range(10):
        a = random.choice(1, 10)
```

This is how far I got but I know my second line is what I gotta change (probably)
Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet does what you described:

```
import random

with open("words.txt", "r") as infile:
    words = [line.rstrip().split(":")[1] for line in infile]
    for i in range(10):
        print (random.choice(words))
```

The `rstrip()` call is necessary to remove the newline character at the end of each line, and `split(":")` splits the line on the colon character, so `[1]` will return the second part. The whole expression is inside a list comprehension, so it will be repeated for every line of the file, and the result is collected in the list `words`.

Comment: Thank you, and for explaining it aswell!

Answer (score 0):

This is close. After reading the `words.txt` file, you can use the `split()` method on a string, for example:

```py
print("example:1".split(":"))
# ['example', '1']
```

If you want to print out "la biblioteca" and skip past "library":

```py
import random

with open("words.txt", "r") as infile:

    # Read a list of words from the file
    words = infile.read().splitlines()
    # Replace word strings with lists where they've been split on ":"
    words = [word.split(":") for word in words]

    for i in range(10):
        # Choose a random word from the words
        a = random.choice(words)

        # Only print the right portion
        print(a[1])
```